# Differential of the identity function: how to show that $\Delta x = dx$, in order to explain the general definition of the differential $dy$.

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I'm trying to get familarized with the notion of " differential" ( in order to understand some basic physics equations involving this notion).

My question deals with the substitution of " $\Delta x$" with " $dx$" in the defnition of " $dy$".

The defnition of $dy$ is

$dy= f'(x) \Delta x$   ( since , by defnition $f'(x)= dy/ \Delta x$)

( visually, $dy$ is, so to say, the tangential or linear  increase of $y$).

In the above formula , one substitutes $dx$ for $\Delta x$ , in order to get :

$dy= f'(x) dx$.

If I am correct, the substitution can be justified by applying the general formula of the differential to the identity function ( f(x)=x) , but I cannot figure out how it is done, nor what it gives visually.

In brief, how to show that $\Delta x = dx$.

In the image below : the vertical segment SR is $dy$ and the horizontal segment PR is $\Delta x$.

[image]

Comment: It depends on the exact approach in the book you're studying, but one approach I've seen is that $dx:=\Delta x$ *by definition*, and then you only make the distinction between $\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$ and $dy=f'(x)\Delta x=f'(x)dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential denotes the *linear part* of the variation (wrt the independent variable).

When $y=f(x)$,

$$\Delta y=f(x+\Delta x)-f(x),$$ while

$$dy=f'(x)\Delta x.$$

There is a non-linear remainder, $\Delta y=f'(x)\Delta x+r(x,\Delta x)=dy+r(x,\Delta x)$.

In the case of the independent variable $x$, the function is the identity and that's why

$$dx=x'\Delta x=\Delta x.$$

$dx$ is the linear part of the variation $\Delta x$ of itself.

Comment: So with $y=f(x)= x$ ( $f$ being the identity function) the general formula gives : $dy=d/dx [x] .\Delta x \rightarrow dy= 1.\Delta x = \Delta x$. But since ( by hypothesis $y=x$ ) we have finally : $x = \Delta x$. Is the derivation correct?

Comment: @FloridusFloridi: no, the conclusion is $\Delta y=dy=dx=\Delta x$.

Comment: You're right! I should have substituted $x$ for $y$ in the expression $dy$! Thanks a lot!

Comment: So with $y=f(x)= x$ ( $f$ being the identity function) the general formula gives : $dy=d/dx [x] .\Delta x \rightarrow dy= 1.\Delta x = \Delta x$. But since ( by hypothesis $y=x$, *implying $dy=dx$* ) we have finally : $dx = \Delta x$.